# How does a css file know what to call a linked font style?

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML and CSS together to break into the world of programming, and this is the first real problem I've run in to that I can't figure out on my own. Of course, it's a process that can be mindlessly replicated, but I want to understand why it works the way it does.

Currently, I'm learning to link fonts, specifically from google fonts, to expand the resources I have to make a website. The piece of code I'm given is `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`. From what I understand, this tells the html document to reference the listed website when an instance of "Abril Fatface" comes up. My question is: how does the computer know to reference the website when I specify in the styling that I want "Abril Fatface"? In other words, how does it know what to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just including a css file, if you open it, the name is in the property font-family. In this case:

```
font-family: 'Abril Fatface';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone can break this down even better than I, but a quick search of `use google fonts in css` gave me this [Getting Started guide from Google](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).

**Here are some highlights:**

1. Add a stylesheet link to request the desired web font(s):

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Font+Name">
```

2. Style an element with the requested web font, either in a stylesheet:

```
.css-selector {
font-family: 'Font Name', serif;
}
```

What I understood from this is that the Google Font API has a font family parameter where each word in the font family name is separated by a `+` symbol. The [CSS font-family property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) accepts values as provided and will even accept multiple values. Fortunately, Google's API lets you provide multiple font families if you separate them with a pipe symbol `|` like so:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine|Inconsolata|Droid+Sans
```

This is mostly an explanation of why it works. If you want to dig deep into the how, Google also has [documentation explaining their API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api). However, if you are brand new to web development, this might be a bit much.

**TL;DR** It might be enough to know that the API provides font family information from its servers to your page using formatting known as "JSON" or (J)ava(S)cript (O)bject (N)otation. JSON is a relatively simple way of storing and transporting various combinations of data on the web.

If you want to better understand JSON and APIs, I highly recommend digging into [FreeCodeCamp's curriculum](https://www.freecodecamp.org/). I've personally learned a lot there.